# Making colors consistent in side by side Pie Charts

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

can anyone please help me to change the color from dark blue to light blue in these charts.

Thanks!

```
begin{centering}
\begin{subfigure}
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[scale=0.7]
\pie[text = legend] {
21/0-1,
41/3-2,
22/6-3,
22/Over100
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[scale=0.7]
\pie[text = legend] {
63/0-2,
32/3-5,
8/6-10,
3/Over 10
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Experience}
%\end{adjustwidth}
\label{fig:1}
\end{centering}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify colors by adding the key `color= {}` to the `\pie` command. Check the following example:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 

\begin{scope}[scale=0.7]

\pie[text = legend,
color = {
violet!50,
cyan!50,
yellow!50,
orange!50},] { 21/0-1, 41/3-2, 22/6-3, 22/Over100 } \end{scope} 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which yields:
[image]
All colors now are 50% original color + 50% white color. Order of colors corresponds to the order of data provided. For example: `violet!50` corresponds to 0-1 case.
I added `xcolor` with `dvipsnames` option to access to a [list of 68 predefined colors](https://latexdraw.com/predefined-latex-colors-dvipsnames/).

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: You're welcome :)